# How to edit Field Level Security of Attachment Object (Notes & Attachments)?

Tags: attachment, object

is there a way to edit the Field Level Security for the Notes & Attachments object? I've tried from both Lightning and Classic but I can't find the object and a way to edit it...

Comment: I doubt you can access that section, but may I know for what purpose would you want to access the Field Level Security?

Answer (score 0):

Notes and Attachments do not have security built into it. It's security is strictly governed by parent record. You should avoid using them and instead use [Salesforce Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.collab_files_overview.htm&type=5) and [Enhanced Notes](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000337292&type=1).

Salesforce Files and Enhanced Notes are based on the Salesforce Content object that has options to configure security bases on your need.